# How to convert datetime from character string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
select dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id, sum(dbo.IN_Invoices.in_total) as Total
from CLOI_ClientOrderItems
inner join IN_Invoices on CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId=IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId
where dbo.IN_Invoices.in_date_issued='2014-01-21 12:30:51.190'
group by cl_id;
```

Comment: Explain properly what you want ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
select 
    dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id, 
    sum(dbo.IN_Invoices.in_total) as Total
from 
    CLOI_ClientOrderItems
    inner join IN_Invoices 
on 
    CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId=IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId
where 
    dbo.IN_Invoices.in_date_issued=CONVERT(datetime, '2014-01-21 12:30:51.190', 120)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id, sum(dbo.IN_Invoices.in_total) as Total
from CLOI_ClientOrderItems
inner join IN_Invoices on CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId=IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId
where dbo.IN_Invoices.in_date_issued=CAST('2014-01-21 12:30:51.190' AS Date)
group by cl_id;
```

Comment: where dbo.IN_Invoices.in_date_issued=CAST('2014-01-21 12:30:51.190' AS DateTime)                                                              instade of date if i pass month like march